# What's the clean way to rollback a hung OBIEE 11.1.1.7 installation

Tags: oracle

Looks like using the deinstall option would wipe out the entire HOME & BI cluster. While we are trying to restore down to the 11.1.1.6 previous installation.

Windows platform. We were using the software-only in-place upgrade.

(couldn't find the OBIEE tag here)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: There is no need to rollback the 7.x installation. New one can be rolled over the existing one, even if didn't finish. The only thing that would make sense to do by hand could be the removal of the previous HOMES, so that you don't generate more and more of these.